# NoClassDefFoundError when using a dependency from my own project

Tags: java, maven

I am learning Maven and Javaee.
I have 2 EJB projects. EJB1 and EJB2.
In my EJB1 pom.xml I have the dependency to EJB2:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>learning</groupId>
    <artifactId>EJB2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

In a EJB1 class I have:

```
MyDTO dto = new MyDTO(); //MyDTO is stored in EJB2 project
```

Eclipse finds it and compiles.
Maven install also works.

But when I deploy to Wildfly I get a  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mypackage.MyDTO

My DTO is defined like this:

```
public class MyDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String str = "this is a real DTO";

    public String getString() {
        return str;
    }
}
```

I tried deploying only EJB1.ejb and EJB2.ejb files in my wildfly (using eclipse), but I got the same error.

Am I missing something?

EDIT:

These are the pom for the projects:

EJB1 pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>learning</groupId>
    <artifactId>EJB1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <name>EJB1</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>learning</groupId>
             <artifactId>EJB2</artifactId>
             <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
             <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

EJB2 pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>learning</groupId>
    <artifactId>EJB2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <name>EJB2</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: is the MYDTO.class in your jar? post your maven build section

Comment: what are the package types in your EJB1.xml & EJB2.xml ? Are they JARs or WARs or EARs ?

Comment: @redFIVE The MyDTO.class is in EJB2.jar, but not in EJB1.jar (of course). I will post the maven build section soon

Comment: @Arkantos please see update

Comment: When you're deploying your project, did you check if your EJB1.jar & EJB2.jar are present inside WEB-INF/lib directory ?

Comment: I solved it by creating an EAR and packaging both ejb packages in it. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating an EAR and packaging both ejb packages in it. Thanks for your help :)